# what(): locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid

Tags: debian, kali-linux, locale

I have a Kali Linux where I cannot install any packages. `locale` is not working and I cannot install it what can I do? I changed `sources.list` but it's of no help, I tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` it tells me:

```
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
dpkg: error: configuration error: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch:1: unknown option 'foreign-architecture'
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: locales is not installed
```

Comment: Your title makes no sense to me, but this other question may be of relevance. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399626/4778

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) setting is bad. Make sure that `echo $PATH` as a non-root user lists `/usr/bin` and `/bin`, and as the root user also `/usr/sbin` and `/sbin`. However, `dpkg` emits a warning in that case so if that warning was absent then this isn't the problem.

The `locale` command is part of a package that is marked as “essential” (`libc-bin`). To uninstall it, you have to type a full sentence at the confirmation prompt. This isn't something you can do by accident.

You might have removed the binary. Once again this won't happen automatically, it has to be a consequence of something you did while running as root. Be careful when running as root, only use the root account to do things that you can't do from your normal account. To reinstall the `libc-bin` package including the `locale` command, run this command as root:

```
apt-get --reinstall install libc-bin
```

You don't appear to have a lot of Linux experience. Kali Linux is a distribution for experienced security professionals, designed to run security-related tools in a virtual machine easily. It isn't designed for a permanent installation and it isn't designed for beginners. If you aren't an experienced Linux user, use a more friendly distribution such as elementary OS, Linux Mint or Ubuntu.

Comment: apt-get is not working it says :root@mr00:~# apt-get --reinstall install libc-bin
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
Aborted

Comment: @GiorgiGavasheli Run `export LC_ALL=C; unset LANGUAGE` and try again. If you still get this error, then there's something seriously broken and without knowing how you got there it's difficult to help you. I'd suggest reinstalling, and this time don't go about editing or removing files when you don't know what they're for.

Comment: in our case we have a split toolchain. the OS and all `/usr/lib` are built with an old gcc and our code wanted newer gcc. so we have our non-OS version of libc which our programs used but OS didn't. Hit this crash, and suggestiong by @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' solved the problem. Not sure if related to libc issues or what, but worked.